# Interrupted System Call in GIT

Tags: git, intellij-idea

While checking out a branch I got an error saying

```
"Some untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout.
     Please move or remove them before you can checkout. View them"
```

Later I have deleted those untracked files and tried to checkout again. But now Iam facing the issue below as:

```
Failed to read object 5df02069fcff5919daf91215f7706fc826c76: Interrupted system call
```

I am using Intellij IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some untracked files. So, do `commit` or `stash`.

```
$ git commit -am 'message'          # add & commit
$ git checkout -b <new-branch>      # checkout to new branch

Or,
$ git add .
$ git stash                         # stash the changes
$ git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

Comment: now if I need to check out existing branch, I have tried git checkout <new-banch> which again showing error of "Some untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout.
     Please move or remove them before you can checkout. View them"

Comment: You've changed maybe in same line of same file(s), so, conflicts occurring. So, best way is to `commit your changes in current branch` then checkout to another exiting branch.

Comment: I didnt make any changes. and my changelist is empty. but still whenever want to check out any other existing branch, facing this issue.

Comment: Make sure `git status` does not show any change. Try `git reset --hard HEAD` the do checkout.

Comment: am not seeing the above thing for the command "git status". I am seeing that my branch is upto date. whatever I do, this issue is going forever.

Comment: Actually "Some untracked working tree files..." error means you've some untracked files and conflicting with banch you want to checkout. BTY, if you create a new branch (`b2`) frome `master` then back to your current branch (say, `b1`). Does `git checkout b1` work ?

Comment: nope. checking out branch after new branch, also getting the same error.